# Calculating percentile of a value given low, lower quartile, median, mean, upper quartile, and high

Tags: python, statistics

I've written some python code trying to calculate percentile, however the values given are obviously wrong.

```
low=int(input("enter low"))
lower_quartile=int(input("lower_quartile"))
mean=int(input("mean"))
median=int(input("median"))
upper_quartile=int(input("upper_quartile"))
high=int(input("high"))
value=int(input("value"))


def calculate_percentile(low, lower_quartile, mean, median, upper_quartile, high, value):
    # Calculate the interquartile range (IQR)
    iqr = upper_quartile - lower_quartile

    # Calculate the distance between the mean and the median in terms of the number of IQRs
    distance = (mean - median) / iqr

    # Calculate the distance between the given value and the median in terms of the number of IQRs
    value_distance = (value - median) / iqr

    # Calculate the percentile based on the given formula
    if value >= median:
        percentile = 50 + value_distance + (distance / 2)
    else:
        percentile = 50 + value_distance - (distance / 2)

    return percentile

test1=calculate_percentile(low, lower_quartile, mean, median, upper_quartile, high, value)
print(test1)
```

```
enter low 50
lower_quartile 65
mean 70
median 71
upper_quartile 80
high 90
value 90
51.233333333333334
```

Given What seems to be the issue with this code? Given a value of 90 with this dataset, the percentile should be 100%, I also see this issue with other inputs.

Comment: So you have a function that attempts to compute something using a totally unjustified logic, and it doesn't work. So why do you think your unjustified logic should work? [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize, you have a value, the mean, and the 0/25/50/75/100 percentiles, and want to know an approximate percentile number for your value.

The mean can be influenced by the values in the other percentiles. Say your value is between 25% and 50%, then the mean can be solely influenced by the values between 75% and 100%.
So the mean doesn't help at all, and can be omitted in the calculation.

A reasonable guess would be to compute the fitting quarter first, and then interpolate there. However, note that it's only a guess.

With `low = 0` and `lower_quartile = 500`, a reasonable guess for the value `400` would be *20%*. But the underlying values could be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 500]` or `[0, 490, 491, 492, 493, 500]`, with radically different answers for the real percentile of 400.

Given a bunch of known percentiles, here's how you can make this guess:

```
import itertools

low = 50
lower_quartile = 65
mean = 70
median = 71
upper_quartile = 80
high = 90
value = 90

percentiles = (
    (0, low), (25, lower_quartile), (50, median), (75, upper_quartile),
    (100, high))

def guess_percentile(known_percentiles, value):
    assert value >= known_percentiles[0][1]
    assert value <= known_percentiles[-1][1]

    for lower, upper in itertools.pairwise(known_percentiles):
        lower_percent, lower_value = lower
        upper_percent, upper_value = upper

        if not (lower_value <= value <= upper_value):
            continue  # Not in this percentile range

        # Where in this quartile are we? between 0 (=lower) and 1(=upper)
        in_quartile = (value - lower_value) / (upper_value - lower_value)

        return lower_percent + (upper_percent - lower_percent) * in_quartile

guess = guess_percentile(percentiles, value)
print(f'Best guess for percentile of {value} is {guess}%')
```